# Checking a radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

I want to check a radio button based on the culture which is set in the "culture" variable in the @helper method. During debugging, I know the the variable is set; it's just not checking the English or Spanish radio button.

Could someone tell me how I can do this based on the below code or if there is an easier way for the code, that would be fine too. I'm using MVC 3 Razor.

```
@helper selected(string c, string culture)
    {
        if (c == culture)
        {
            @:checked="checked"
        }  
    }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
            $(this).parents("form").submit();
        });

        // highlight selected language
        $("input[type='radio']:checked").next().css("font-weight", "bold");
    });
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "setCulture" }))
{
    <fieldset id="setCulture">
        <legend>@Resources.SelectCulture</legend>
        <input name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" type="radio" @selected("en-us", culture) />
        <label for="en-us">
            English</label>
        <br />
        <input name="culture" id="es-es" value="es-es" type="radio" @selected("es-es", culture) />
        <label for="es-es">
            Español</label>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your culture variable equaled either "en-us" or "es-es" what you have already should work. I don't think it equals what you think it does. You could try

```
<input name="culture" id="testing" value="testing" type="radio" @selected("testing","testing") />
```

to test what you have.

That said I'd recommend using the `RadioButtonFor` method with a strongly typed view

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public string Culture { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

@model YourViewModel

@*Rest of view*@

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Culture, "en-us")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Culture, "es-us")
```